# How to convert all .txt files in a folder from utf16 to utf8 that they can be read in R?

Tags: r

Just like the title says...how can I embed a code into my script to change all files in the folder from utf16 to utf8 to make it easier for R to read?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### R can read `utf-16` files

R is able to read `utf-16` files, so it may not be necessary to convert them. However, to answer the question, here is:

1. An R function to copy all `utf-16` encoded files in a directory to a new folder with `utf-8` encoding. This reads each file into RAM at once, which may be problematic with large files.
2. A list of native OS approaches to changing the encoding for a directory of files (both Linux/Mac and Windows):

   1. Linux/Mac: a `bash` script using `iconv` which converts file streams, i.e. avoids storing the whole file in memory at once.
   2. Windows: a pure PowerShell approach using `Get-Content`, which reads the entire file at once.
   3. Windows: a PowerShell approach with some embedded C# which streams the file line by line.
3. A summary of how to read a `utf-16` csv file into R using `base` R, `data.table` and `tidyverse`. If you just want to read the files into R, there's no need to copy them, and this is probably the right approach.

### 1. R function to change file encoding

You can write an R function to read in a file in `utf-16` and then write it out in `utf-8`:

```r
convert_file_to_utf8 <- function(in_file, out_file, encoding = "utf-16") {
    in_file_conn <- file(in_file, encoding = encoding)
    txt <- readLines(in_file_conn)
    close(in_file_conn)

    # Create out directory
    if (!dir.exists(dirname(out_file))) dir.create(dirname(out_file))

    # Write file with new encoding
    out_file_conn <- file(out_file, encoding = "utf-8")
    writeLines(txt, out_file_conn)
    close(out_file_conn)
}
```

If you want to do this to an entire directory then you can write another function to call this function:

```r
create_utf8_dir <- function(in_dir = "./utf16dir/", out_dir = "./utf8dir/") {
    files <- dir(in_dir, full.names = TRUE)
    for (in_file in files) {
        out_file <- sub(in_dir, out_dir, in_file, fixed = TRUE)
        convert_file_to_utf8(in_file, out_file)
    }
}
```

Running `create_utf8_dir()` will copy the `utf-16` encoded contents of the directory `"./utf16dir/"` to a directory called `"./utf8dir/"` (which it will create if it does not exist).

### 2. Native OS approaches to changing a file encoding

However, if the files are large, an approach which reads in the entirety of each file at once will use a lot of RAM.

#### 2.1 bash

If you are use Linux/Mac I would use [`iconv`](https://ss64.com/bash/iconv.html) which can [change a file encoding while streaming the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206232/how-to-change-encoding-of-a-text-file-without-openning-the-file-in-shell-program), i.e. never keeping the entire file contents in RAM. For one file you can do:

```bash
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 mtcars.csv > mtcars_utf8.csv
```

To convert all files in the directory `./utf16dir` into `./utf8dir`:

```bash
IN_ENCODING=UTF16
OUT_ENCODING=UTF8
OUT_DIR=utf8dir
for f in ./utf16dir/*; do
    basename="$(basename ${f%.*})"
    extension=${f##*.}  
    outfile="./$OUT_DIR/$basename$OUT_ENCODING.$extension"
    echo $outfile
    iconv -f $IN_ENCODING -t $OUT_ENCODING $f > $outfile
done
```

#### 2.2 PowerShell

#### 2.2.1 Pure PowerShell

If you are using Windows, you can use the following pattern:

```
(Get-Content -path mtcars.csv) | Set-Content -Encoding ASCII -Path mtcarsutf8.csv
```

To abstract this to all files in a folder:

```
$in_dir = "./utf16dir/"
$out_dir = "./utf8dir/"

If (!(test-path -PathType container $out_dir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $out_dir
}
Get-ChildItem $in_dir | 
Foreach-Object {
    $outfile = $out_dir + $_.BaseName + "_utf8" + $_.Extension
    Write-Output $outfile
    (Get-Content -path $_.FullName) | Set-Content -Encoding ASCII -Path $outfile
}
```

Again this will copy the `utf-16` encoded contents of the directory `"./utf16dir/"` to a directory called `"./utf8dir/"` (which it will create if it does not exist), appending `"_utf8"` to the file names.

There are drawbacks to this approach:

1. I set the encoding to ASCII which is a subset of `utf-8`. That's OK here as I know all the characters are ASCII characters. If that's not the case, you can change `ASCII` to `UTF-8`. However, Windows uses `utf-8-bom`. It is not entirely straightforward to remove the remove the Byte Order Mark (BOM) - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom) if you have non-ASCII characters.
2. This reads the entire file into RAM at once, like the R approach.

### 2.2.2 Powershell with embedded C#

You can overcome both of these limitations by using C# [within Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65841115/12545041) to read a `utf-16` encoded file line by line, and then write out a `utf-8` file:

```
$code = @"
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace ProcessLargeFile
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void ConvertLine(string line, StreamWriter sw)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
        public static void ConvertFile(string path, string inDir, string outDir) {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open));
            string outPath = path.Replace(inDir, outDir);
            Console.WriteLine(outPath);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(outPath, System.IO.FileMode.Append));
            try {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream){
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    ConvertLine(line, sw);
                }
            } finally {
                sr.Close();
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        static void ConvertDir(string inDir, string outDir) {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(inDir);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(outDir);
            foreach(string file in filePaths)
            {
                ConvertFile(file, inDir, outDir);
            }
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            string inDir = args[0];
            string outDir = args[1];
            ConvertDir(inDir, outDir);
        }
    }
}
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
[ProcessLargeFile.Program]::Main(@("utf16dir/", "utf8dir/"))
```

Again this copies the content of `"utf16dir/"` to `"utf8dir/"`. You can change the input and output directories by changing the arguments in the final line. This approach streams the files and writes out pure `utf-8` (with no BOM).

### 3. base R, data.table and tidyverse methods to read a utf-16 file

In your question you state you wish to change the encoding in order to make it easier for R to read the files. R is able to read `utf-16` files, provided you set the `encoding` argument when you create the file connection with [`file()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/connections).

I'll set out here how to read a `utf-16` csv file with base R and popular alternatives. Assume for example that you are trying to read the following file:

```r
in_file <- "./utf16dir/mtcars.csv"
```

#### base R

```r
in_file_conn <- file(in_file, encoding = encoding)
read.csv(text = readLines(in_file_conn))
```

#### data.table

```r
in_file_conn <- file(in_file, encoding = encoding)
data.table::fread(
    text = readLines(in_file_conn)
)
```

#### readr

```r
readr::read_csv(
    in_file,
    locale = readr::locale(encoding = "utf-16")
)
```

Depending on your ultimate goal, rather than copying all the files in the directory, you may simply wish to read in the `utf-16` encoded files.